# Serving static directory on subdomain with assets

Tags: nginx, static-content

I have a html presentation which I would like to serve on a subdomain on my server. It just consists of some static html files and some assets ([the Github is here](https://github.com/dtuite/make_js_like_ruby)).

I'm trying to write an nginx config file which will serve the presentation. What I have so far is the following:

```
server {
  server_name make-js-like-ruby.grinnick.com;

  root /home/dtuite/stuff/presentations/make_js_like_ruby/introduction;

  access_log off;
  error_log off;
}
```

The actual root file is in `/introduction/index.html`. Nginx seems to serve that file by default which is fine. The problem is that none of the assets seems to be available on the page. [You can see the problem live here.](http://make-js-like-ruby.grinnick.com/).

How do I make the assets are available but also make sure that the subdomain roots to the index file correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Move Root Path

Your current directory structure (on your hard drive) is like following

```
/home/dtuite/stuff/presentations/make_js_like_ruby/
    code/
    core/
    extensions/
    images/
    introduction/
    themes/
```

However, your root path is set to

```
/home/dtuite/stuff/presentations/make_js_like_ruby/introduction
```

The web server will not access any file outside that path. Since `themes`, `images`, etc., are all outside the above path, their content will not be served.

### Fix

I suggest moving the root path one level up

```
root /home/dtuite/stuff/presentations/make_js_like_ruby;
```

Then move the `index.html` into `/home/dtuite/stuff/presentations/make_js_like_ruby`. Of course links within `index.html` will have to be modified accordingly.